# filter a table on a cluster key efficiently

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake table, with a clustering key with the format `yyyy-mm-dd-hh`, and I would like to filter it on all the values of a certain date.

I have written the where clause in those ways:

1. `WHERE dt >= current_date() || '-00' AND dt <= current_date() || '-23'` - took 0.7 seconds
2. `WHERE dt IN (current_date() || '-00',current_date() || '-01',current_date() || '-02',current_date() || '-03',current_date() || '-04',current_date() || '-05',current_date() || '-06',current_date() || '-07',current_date() || '-08',current_date() || '-09',current_date() || '-10',current_date() || '-11',current_date() || '-12',current_date() || '-13',current_date() || '-14',current_date() || '-15',current_date() || '-16',current_date() || '-17',current_date() || '-18',current_date() || '-19',current_date() || '-20',current_date() || '-21',current_date() || '-22',current_date() || '-23')` - took the same as #1
3. `WHERE dt LIKE  current_date() || '%'` - took 2.9 seconds
4. `WHERE left(dt, 10) = current_date` - took 9.2 seconds

and I set `ALTER SESSION SET USE_CACHED_RESULT = FALSE` to make sure the result cache is not being used

my questions are:

1. is the a more efficient way to query than #1?
2. what type of queries can take advantage of the clustering? I would expect #3 to perform similar to #1, so I'm wandering what are the rules to write an efficient query

Answer (score 1):

@lev did you check query profile for all these queries,it's highly likely that query process more micro-partitions in 3 &4 than 1 &2.

Comment: I check the query profile, and indeed all queries processed the same amount of partitions, but for #4, the value of `Bytes scanned` was doubled than the other queries